# .NET Core The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis-7

Full *log*:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework **Microsoft.NETCore.App**, version _1.1.2_ was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed 
at:
      \
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.2'.
```

The browser says:

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
```

I am trying to run my APP on a Windows 2008 IIS 7 server. I've created a new Application Pool called NetCore and assigned it to my site.

I have .NET Core 2.0.2 SDK installed on the server.
I also installed Windows Server Hosting.

My csproj is set to  netcoreapp1.1

I have read all related posts on Github to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try downloading/installing version `1.1.2` of `.NET Core` on your server from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases). I believe you have to have the `SDK` version that matches your app.

Comment: Cheers for that, I thought 2.0.2 would have covered it.
FYI Additionally I had to download the Windows Server Hosting Bundle 1.0.4
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=844461

Comment: I had same issue even having all references to Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0. Installing 1.1.7 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the system environment variable "PATH". The path "C:\Program Files\dotnet\;" should preceed the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\".